# Verify EU Digital COVID Certificate from Linux (without a smartphone)

Tags: linux, health, qr-code

I will soon need to verify some [EU Digital COVID Certificates](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/coronavirus-response/safe-covid-19-vaccines-europeans/eu-digital-covid-certificate_en).
I have a Linux machine (Ubuntu 21/04) with a webcam, which should be all the technology needed for this.
However, all the software I can find seem to be smartphone apps and I don’t want to get a smartphone just for this purpose.
Is there any solution that allows me to do this without a smartphone?

Notes:

- I know that some of the existing software is open-source and but I don’t want to go through the hassle of porting it myself.
- I don’t care how many loopholes the certificate system has. Assume that I have no alternative to verifying those certificates.
- I prefer open-source solutions (and don’t expect much else to be out there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cobbled together a native standalone solution using [Zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) for barcode reading and [Verify EHC](https://github.com/panzi/verify-ehc) for certificate verification.

#### Preparation

1. Get the required tools:

   ```
   sudo apt install zbar-tools
   git clone https://github.com/panzi/verify-ehc
   pip3 install -r verify-ehc/requirements.txt
   ```

   This assumes an Ubuntu/Debian environment, but should be easy to modify for others.
2. Get certificates for Verify EHC.

   ```
   cd verify-ehc
   ./verify_ehc.py --certs-from DE --save-certs DE_certs.json
   ```

   This throws an error for me, but the download seems to be fine nonetheless.

   You can do without this step, but then reading each certificate takes very long.
   `DE` instructs to download from the German trust-list service.
   You can choose other countries (as specified by `./verify_ehc --help`).
   In either case, you need to modify the arguments of the command below.

#### The actual scan

You have to be in the `verify-ehc` folder for this:

```
zbarcam --raw | xargs -i -d "\n" -n1 ./verify_ehc.py --certs-file DE_certs.json "{}"
```

This uses `zbarcam` to grab QR codes from the camera. Whenever you see a green square appearing on the video output, a QR code was successfully detected. The code is then passed on to Verify EHC, which prints out the verification and the contents of the certificates to the console.

#### Pros and cons

- Of all the tools I tested so far, Zbarcam has by far the best barcode detection (with a webcam).
- Doesn’t require an Internet connection for scanning.
- You get the entire certificate in JSON format according to [this specification](https://ec.europa.eu/health/sites/default/files/ehealth/docs/covid-certificate_json_specification_en.pdf). It is mostly human-readable, but a few key items are not.
  For example, `v-dn` is the number of vaccinations and `v-sd` is the number of vaccinations in the vaccination scheme (and thus somebody is vaccinated if `v-dn` is at least `v-sd` and the waiting time after the last shot has passed).
- You get more information than you need for verifying, which may be a privacy concern for whose certificate you scan.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by running Android on a [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and giving it access to your web cam. In detail:

1. Install VirtualBox with the extension pack. On Ubuntu:

   ```
    sudo apt install virtualbox-qt virtualbox-ext-pack
   ```
2. [Download Android x86](https://www.android-x86.org/download). I used the Version 9 64-bit ISO, but I guess others will work as well.
3. Run `virtualbox` and create a new box with the following settings:

   - Type: *Linux*
   - Version: *Other Linux (64-bit)*
   - IDE Secondary Device: [The ISO from Step 2]
   - at least 1 GB of RAM access
   - System → Processor: at least 2 processors
   - System → Acceleration → Paravirtualisation Interface: *KVM*
   - Display → Screen → Graphics Controller: *VboxSVGA*
4. Start your virtual machine and install Android:

   1. *Advanced Options*
   2. *Auto Installation*
   3. Say *yes* to erasing `/dev/sda` (if you are sure you set up a virtual disk)
   4. *Reboot* and switch off the virtual machine.
   5. Remove the disk form the secondary device.
5. Start the virtual machine and **activate your camera via *Devices → Webcams* before booting**. You have to do that every time you start the virtual box.
6. Set up the operating system
7. Open *Play Store,* search for a Covid check software, e.g., *CovPass Check* and install it.
8. Run *CovPass Check.* It should automatically activate your web cam as soon as it needs it.

Parts of the installation instructions were inspired by [this Heise article](https://www.heise.de/tipps-tricks/Android-in-VirtualBox-installieren-so-geht-s-4155176.html).

Answer (score 0):

By now, there are some browser-based solutions available.

- The most verbose official one I could find, is [Green Check](https://greencheck.gv.at/), which is operated by the Austrian Ministry for Health. It is in German, but results are communicated as big checkmarks. The only thing you need to know are the different levels of validation, which are as of now:

  - 3G: vaccinated, recovered, or tested
  - 2.5G: vaccinated, recovered, or PCR-tested
  - 2G+: (vaccinated or recovered) and tested
  - 2G: vaccinated or recovered
  - 1G: vaccinated
- The [Digital Covide Cert Checker](https://app.digitalcovidcertchecker.gov.ie/) is from the Irish Department of Health. It is in English, but less verbose than the Austrian one.

Comment: What about 5G??

Comment: @user1271772: I don’t know what you are referring to. The terms _3G, 2G,_ and similar originate from the abbreviations of the German words for vaccinated (“geimpft”), recovered (“genesen”), and tested (“getestet”). Unless somebody unexpectedly finds two other things that allow you to hygienically problematic events and start with *g* in German, there won’t be any _5G._

Comment: I don't think I understand "allow you to hygienically problematic events"

Comment: @user1271772: try: “grant you access to events that otherwise have a high chance of Covid transmissions”

Comment: "allow you to attend hygienically problematic events" would have been better, or even better than that would be the same with "dangerous" instead of "problematic", but anyway thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, virtualization-based, with
Host: ChromeOS (Chromebook), Guest: Linux

You could get a Chromebook which comes with ChromeOS. ChromeOS can install most Android apps (COVID cert apps) from the Android App Store.

Inside ChromeOS, you can install a Debian-Based Linux Distribution ([Crostini](https://chromeos.dev/en/linux)?) which is being developed by Google. And you can work out a solution where the QR code is scanned by an app, and transferred to Linux via a shared folder.

Maybe this approach does not work for you; besides, you've accepted someone else's answer already.

However some *other* readers might find my answer useful, in the future.

Comment: If I am already on an OS which can run Android apps, why would I would I go through the trouble to transfer this to a virtual machine?

Comment: I don't know. Read certficate metadata, perhaps? Do something with the Certificate data that requires Linux/Unix  processing , with some command-line tools? It might be convenient to have everything on one machine.